# How to Send Kubernetes Logs to AWS CloudWatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

## AWS CloudWatch Logs in Docker

Setting an AWS CloudWatch Logs driver in `docker` is done with `log-driver=awslogs` and `log-opt`, for example -

```
#!/bin/bash

docker run \
    --log-driver=awslogs \
    --log-opt awslogs-region=eu-central-1 \
    --log-opt awslogs-group=whatever-group \
    --log-opt awslogs-stream=whatever-stream \
    --log-opt awslogs-create-group=true \
    wernight/funbox \
        fortune
```

## My Problem

I would like to use AWS CloudWatch logs in a Kubernetes cluster, where each pod contains a few Docker containers. Each deployment would have a separate Log Group, and each container would have a separate stream. I could not find a way to send the logging parameters to the docker containers via Kubernetes `create` / `apply`.

## My Question

**How can I send the `log-driver` and `log-opt` parameters to a Docker container in a pod / deployment?**

## What have I tried

- Setting relevant parameters for the Docker daemon on each machine. It's possible, but this way all the containers on the same machine would share the same stream - therefore irrelevant for my case.
- RTFM for [`kubectl apply`](https://kubernetes-v1-4.github.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_apply/)
- Reading the [relevant README in `kops`](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/vendor/github.com/docker/docker/docs/admin/logging/awslogs.md)
- Read [`Kubernetes Logging Architecture`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/)

Comment: Try out CloudWatch Container Insights, https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/05/cloudwatch-container-insights-for-eks-and-kubernetes-preview/. It has a fluentd yaml for application logs, data plane logs (kubelet and container runtime), and host logs.

Answer (score 19):

From what I understand, Kubernetes prefer Cluster-level logging to Docker logging driver.

We could use [fluentd](http://fluentd.org) to collect, transform, and push container logs to CloudWatch Logs.

All you need is to create a fluentd DaemonSet with ConfigMap and Secret. Files can be found in [Github](https://github.com/zerda/kube-fluentd-cloudwatch). It has been tested with Kubernetes v1.7.5.

The following are some explains.

## In

With DaemonSet, fluentd collect every container logs from the host folder `/var/lib/docker/containers`.

## Filter

[fluent-plugin-kubernetes_metadata_filter](https://github.com/fabric8io/fluent-plugin-kubernetes_metadata_filter) plugin load the pod's metadata from Kubernetes API server.

The log record would be like this.

```
{
    "log": "INFO: 2017/10/02 06:44:13.214543 Discovered remote MAC 62:a1:3d:f6:eb:65 at 62:a1:3d:f6:eb:65(kube-235)\n",
    "stream": "stderr",
    "docker": {
        "container_id": "5b15e87886a7ca5f7ebc73a15aa9091c9c0f880ee2974515749e16710367462c"
    },
    "kubernetes": {
        "container_name": "weave",
        "namespace_name": "kube-system",
        "pod_name": "weave-net-4n4kc",
        "pod_id": "ac4bdfc1-9dc0-11e7-8b62-005056b549b6",
        "labels": {
            "controller-revision-hash": "2720543195",
            "name": "weave-net",
            "pod-template-generation": "1"
        },
        "host": "kube-234",
        "master_url": "https://10.96.0.1:443/api"
    }
}
```

Make some tags with Fluentd [record_transformer](https://github.com/zerda/kube-fluentd-cloudwatch/blob/master/fluentd-configmap.yaml#L27-L28) filter plugin.

```
{
    "log": "...",
    "stream": "stderr",
    "docker": {
        ...
    },
    "kubernetes": {
        ...
    },
    "pod_name": "weave-net-4n4kc",
    "container_name": "weave"
}
```

## Out

[fluent-plugin-cloudwatch-logs](https://github.com/ryotarai/fluent-plugin-cloudwatch-logs) plugin send to AWS CloudWatch Logs.

With `log_group_name_key` and `log_stream_name_key` configuration, log group and stream name can be any field of the record.

```
<match kubernetes.**>
  @type cloudwatch_logs
  log_group_name_key pod_name
  log_stream_name_key container_name
  auto_create_stream true
  put_log_events_retry_limit 20
</match>
```

Comment: Would this solution keep the containers isolated? Will they be able to read each other's logs?

Comment: Yes, they are isolated with each other. Only the fluentd container can read all container's logs (on it's host), because of the volume mappings.

Comment: Trying to get my head round this.

At the moment I have (using kops) set the docker logDriver to awslogs and all my logs are correctly being sent to CloudWatch but in a single log group. I am trying to find a way to get these into separate log groups per application.

Should I turn off the docker level logging and instead sort with fluentd as you describe above?

Comment: @olly-w can you share how you set Docker logDriver to log to CloudWatch? I was trying to find out how but I read that `docker run` flags for logging backend are not supported by k8s and kops

Comment: @cryanbhu you need to edit the kops cluster e.g. `kops edit cluster` and then set something like:
  docker:
    logDriver: awslogs
    logOpt:
    - awslogs-region=eu-west-1
    - awslogs-group=integration
    - tag={{.Name}}

Answer (score 4):

As per kubernate, Kubernetes provides no native storage solution for log data, but you can integrate many existing logging solutions into your Kubernetes cluster and kubernate [cluster-level-logging-architectures](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#cluster-level-logging-architectures).

> Kubernetes doesn’t specify a logging agent, but two optional logging agents are packaged with the Kubernetes release: Stackdriver Logging for use with Google Cloud Platform, and Elasticsearch. You can find more information and instructions in the dedicated documents. Both use fluentd with custom configuration as an agent on the node.

Fluentd image to send Kubernetes logs to CloudWatch too, so you can use that to [Deploy](https://hub.docker.com/r/whereisaaron/fluentd-kubernetes-cloudwatch/),

Answer (score 4):

You could use a Helm chart to install Fluentd:

```
$ helm install --name my-release incubator/fluentd-cloudwatch
```

This is from:
https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/tree/master/incubator/fluentd-cloudwatch

Answer (score 3):

Sliverfox has a great answer. You don't have to build your own image. Could also directly use fluentd official docker image, fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset:cloudwatch. The code is on [fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset github](https://github.com/fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset).

You could replace the default fluent.conf with the configmap. Like below in the ds.yaml, and write your own fluent.conf in configmap.yaml. For the complete yaml files, you could refer to the example [ds.yaml](https://github.com/cloudstax/firecamp/blob/master/containersvc/k8s/fluentd-cw-ds.yaml) and [configmap.yaml](https://github.com/cloudstax/firecamp/blob/master/containersvc/k8s/fluentd-cw-configmap.yaml) that we wrote.

```
    volumeMounts:
    - name: varlog
      mountPath: /var/log
    - name: varlibdockercontainers
      mountPath: /var/lib/docker/containers
      readOnly: true
    - name: config-volume
      mountPath: /fluentd/etc/
  volumes:
  - name: varlog
    hostPath:
      path: /var/log
  - name: varlibdockercontainers
    hostPath:
      path: /var/lib/docker/containers
  - name: config-volume
    configMap:
      name: fluentd-cw-config
```